# Volcano plot for multiple clusters

Tags: r, ggplot2, cluster-analysis

I am trying to make a volcano plot for different clusters. I have 2 conditions, untreated vs. treated. I have a differential expression excel file that cellranger generated for me but within the file it has multiple clusters each which have a fold change and p value. How do I create a volcano plot that contains all the clusters rather than one? Would I have to do a volcano plot for each cluster and then combine them all somehow?

I used this code to generate the plot for just one of the clusters...

```r
macrophage_list <- read.table("differential_expression_macrophage.csv", header = T, sep = ",")`

EnhancedVolcano(macrophage_list, lab = as.character(macrophage_list$FeatureName), x = 'Cluster1.Log2.Fold.Change', y = 'Cluster1.Adjusted.P.Value', xlim = c(-8,8), title = 'Macrophage', pCutoff = 10e-5, FCcutoff = 1.5, pointSize = 3.0, labSize = 3.0)
```

How do I merge all the information in the excel file to create a volcano plot?

I uploaded each data cluster one by one and then merged them by using rbind, but is there a simpler/quicker way to do this?

output for `dput(gene_list[1:20, 1:14])`

```r
structure(list(Feature.ID = structure(1:20, .Label = c("a", "b", 
"c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", 
"p", "q", "r", "s", "t"), class = "factor"), Feature.Name = structure(1:20, .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", 
"O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T"), class = "factor"), Cluster.1_Mean.Counts = c(0.000960904, 
0.000320301, 0.001281205, 0.000320301, 0.000320301, 0.016335362, 
0.000960904, 0, 0.001601506, 0.000320301, 0.007046627, 0.026585, 
0.017296265, 0.004804518, 0, 0.874742598, 0.017616566, 0.007366928, 
0.008327831, 0.001921807), Cluster.1_Log2.fold.change = c(0.291978774, 
1.954943787, -2.008530337, -2.482461526, 3.539906287, 0.407455991, 
-0.214981215, 1.539906287, 0.802940693, 2.539906287, -1.333136538, 
-1.879953595, -0.52422405, -0.877946228, 1.539906287, -0.629373147, 
1.118442519, 0.170672478, 1.065975099, 1.099333696), Cluster.1_Adjusted.p.value = c(1, 
0.910243711, 0.04672812, 0.080866038, 0.610296549, 0.80063597, 
1, 1, 0.951841603, 0.797013021, 0.103401275, 0.000594428, 0.907754993, 
0.532689631, 1, 0.480958806, 0.078345008, 1, 0.198557945, 0.668312142
), Cluster.2_Mean.Counts = c(0.000902278, 0.001804555, 0.006315943, 
0.004511388, 0, 0.029775159, 0.001804555, 0, 0.002706833, 0, 
0.023459216, 0.128123411, 0.030677437, 0.009022775, 0, 2.174488883, 
0.018947828, 0.019850106, 0.010827331, 0.000902278), Cluster.2_Log2.fold.change = c(0.792589781, 
4.769869705, 0.35201719, 0.839132367, 3.184907204, 1.32985554, 
0.962514783, 3.184907204, 1.725475586, 2.599944703, 0.560416339, 
0.580736324, 0.407299626, 0.184907204, 3.184907204, 0.816580902, 
1.120776867, 1.742684876, 1.409613491, 0.599944703), Cluster.2_Adjusted.p.value = c(1, 
0.153573448, 1, 0.737977734, 1, 0.14478935, 0.853816767, 1, 0.47952604, 
1, 0.65316285, 0.507251471, 0.776636022, 1, 1, 0.346630571, 0.285006452, 
0.060868933, 0.21546202, 1), Cluster.3_Mean.Counts = c(0.001813813, 
0, 0.019045032, 0.00725525, 0, 0.022672657, 0.000906906, 0, 0, 
0, 0.029927908, 0.043531502, 0.046252221, 0.029021001, 0, 3.146057931, 
0.020858845, 0.013603594, 0.008162157, 0), Cluster.3_Log2.fold.change = c(1.455721575, 
2.192687169, 2.008262598, 1.504631175, 3.192687169, 0.9044422, 
0.334706174, 3.192687169, -0.451169021, 2.607724668, 0.931421856, 
-1.032594057, 1.038258504, 1.970294748, 3.192687169, 1.412371018, 
1.26985503, 1.14829305, 0.991053308, -0.451169021), Cluster.3_Adjusted.p.value = c(0.757752635, 
1, 0.032609935, 0.33316083, 1, 0.441825712, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.380305075, 
0.605158722, 0.339946318, 0.016952505, 1, 0.056529024, 0.259458704, 
0.339639234, 0.536765022, 1), Cluster.4_Mean.Counts = c(0.000641899, 
0, 0.002567596, 0.004493293, 0, 0.010270384, 0.003209495, 0, 
0.000641899, 0, 0.028243557, 0.160474756, 0.012196081, 0.005135192, 
0, 1.199709274, 0.005135192, 0.004493293, 0.005777091, 0.001283798
), Cluster.4_Log2.fold.change = c(0.269229783, 1.661547206, -0.886889419, 
0.778904157, 2.661547206, -0.289908942, 1.602653517, 2.661547206, 
0.076584705, 2.076584705, 0.854192284, 0.961549693, -0.967809414, 
-0.644261223, 2.661547206, -0.104384578, -0.790579612, -0.467735811, 
0.459913345, 0.722947751), Cluster.4_Adjusted.p.value = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.584036686, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 20L))
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of your dataset ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example.In your case, I suggest to provide the output of `dput(macrophage_list[1:20,])`

Comment: I have updated the question to include an image of the output.

Comment: I tried to copy and paste but it automatically goes to the image setting.

Comment: No, from my actual excel file.

Comment: I already did, and it prompts me to paste it as an image or else the file is too big.

Comment: I had to delete the genes as it was too big again.

Comment: I edited your `dput` in order to add `Feature.ID` and `Feature.Name`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your dataset, you need to reshape them but first in order to reshape them using the right pattern, we will rename some column names:

```r
colnames(df) <- gsub(".Mean", "_Mean", colnames(df)) 
colnames(df) <- gsub(".Log2", "_Log2", colnames(df))
colnames(df) <- gsub(".Adjus","_Adjus",colnames(df))
```

Now, we can reshape it using the right pattern with `pivot_longer` function from `tidyr` package:

```r
library(tidyr)
final_df <- df %>% pivot_longer(., -c(Feature.ID, Feature.Name), names_to = c("set",".value"), names_pattern = "(.+)_(.+)")

# A tibble: 80 x 6
   Feature.ID Feature.Name set       Mean.Counts Log2.fold.change Adjusted.p.value
   <fct>      <fct>        <chr>           <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
 1 a          A            Cluster.1    0.000961            0.292           1     
 2 a          A            Cluster.2    0.000902            0.793           1     
 3 a          A            Cluster.3    0.00181             1.46            0.758 
 4 a          A            Cluster.4    0.000642            0.269           1     
 5 b          B            Cluster.1    0.000320            1.95            0.910 
 6 b          B            Cluster.2    0.00180             4.77            0.154 
 7 b          B            Cluster.3    0                   2.19            1     
 8 b          B            Cluster.4    0                   1.66            1     
 9 c          C            Cluster.1    0.00128            -2.01            0.0467
10 c          C            Cluster.2    0.00632             0.352           1     
# … with 70 more rows
```

Now, we can create the volcano plot by using `ggplot2` and `ggrepel` libraries for the labeling of `Feature.Name` (if you don't have `ggrepel`, you have to install it):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
ggplot(final_df, aes(x = Log2.fold.change,y = -log10(Adjusted.p.value), label = Feature.Name))+ 
  geom_point()+
  geom_text_repel(data = subset(final_df, Adjusted.p.value < 0.05), 
                  aes(label = Feature.Name))
```

And you get your volcano plot with all clusters merged, all points with the same color, and with labeling of Feature.names with an adjusted p value < 0.05

[image]

Comment: Hi dc37, this is exactly what I'm asking. For this following command, `File %>% pivot_longer(., - FeatureName, names_to = c("set",".value"), names_pattern = "(.+)_(.+)"`, am I substituting what is in "" and if so, to what?

Comment: The easier way will be to rename first your columns names by using few lines that I post at the end of my answer (with `gsub(...)`. It should make your columns looks like my example and it will be easier to pass the command `pivot_longer` with the `names_pattern` without changing anything. Let me know if it is working.

Comment: @Michelle, I edited my answer to provide a solution using your example data. Let me know if it is what you are looking for

Comment: I followed all the steps but looking at the dataset after all the adjustments, the column for FeatureNames is gone and therefore I can't label based on gene but rather by cluster. How do I add the FeatureName column back?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the very last line of code. Is it what you are talking about ?

Comment: I ran this `EnhancedVolcano(df_reshaped, lab = as.character(df_reshaped$FeatureName), x = 'Log2.fold.change', y = 'Adjusted.p.value', xlim = c(-8,8), title = 'Macrophage', pCutoff = 10e-5, FCcutoff = 1.5, pointSize = 3.0, labSize = 3.0)` and got the following error:
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "lab", value = character(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 657888
In addition: Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: 'FeatureName'.

Comment: Feature_Name doesn't exist in the dataset anymore. When I ran `gene_list %>% pivot_longer(., -c(Feature_ID, Feature_Name), names_to = c("set",".value"), names_pattern = "(.+)_(.+)") %>%
+     ggplot(., aes(x = Log2.fold.change,y = -log10(Adjusted.p.value), color = set))+ geom_point()` , this is the error I receive...
Error: Unknown columns `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` and ... 
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: can you post the output of `colnames(gene_list)[1:6]` just before lauching the command `%>% pivot ...`?

Comment: [1] "Feature.ID"                 "Feature.Name"               "Cluster.1_Mean.Counts"     
[4] "Cluster.1_Log2.fold.change" "Cluster.1_Adjusted.p.value" "Cluster.2_Mean.Counts"

Comment: So, in my example, you should have replace `Feature_ID` and `Feature_Name` by the one you have in your dataframe `Feature.ID` and `Feature.Name`. I edited my answer with corresponding code. Something like that should work `gene_list %>% pivot_longer(., -c(Feature.ID, Feature.Name), names_to = c("set",".value"), names_pattern = "(.+)_(.+)") %>% + ggplot(., aes(x = Log2.fold.change,y = -log10(Adjusted.p.value), color = set))+ geom_point()`

Comment: `> gene_list %>% pivot_longer(., -c(Feature.ID, Feature.Name), names_to = c("set",".value"), names_pattern = "(.+)_(.+)") %>% + ggplot(., aes(x = Log2.fold.change,y = -log10(Adjusted.p.value), color = set))+ geom_point()
Error: Can't index beyond the end of a vector.
The vector has length 0 and you've tried to subset element 1.`

Comment: I went to go add the dataset again to start from scratch and this happened `Feature.ID = letters[1:20]
> Feature.Name = LETTERS[1:20]
> gene_list <- cbind(Feature.ID, Feature.Name, gene_list)
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 20, 31328`

Comment: Why are you adding these two columns to your `gene_list` ? Does your `gene_list` dataset does not have already some ID and Name ? If I add them it was because your `dput` was too long to be put entirely in the question, so I re-create a fake dataset. But in your original dataset called `gene_list`, you should already have Feature.ID` and `Feature.Name`

Comment: Awesome, I have generated the volcano plot with ggplot, but now how to I go about labeling with the FeatureName?

Comment: I tried this... `gene_list %>% pivot_longer(., -c(Feature.ID, Feature.Name), names_to = c("set",".value"), names_pattern = "(.+)_(.+)") %>%
+     ggplot(., aes(x = Log2.fold.change,y = -log10(Adjusted.p.value), label = gene_list$Feature.Name, color = set))+ geom_point()
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (626560): label` to get the FeatureNames.

Comment: Also, how to I get everything the same color? Thank you so much for all your help.

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly. But if you still have more question, you should create a new question, the comments section is not the best way to ask for help.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is but the command is taking forever to produce the volcano plot. The first part goes quick but when I run everything as one, it's been taking forever.

Comment: It depends of the size of your dataframe. If you have 20 000 differnt points to plot, it can be a bit long